# APScheduler BackgoundScheduler Start Stop job

Tags: apscheduler

I would like to start a job monitoring at regular interval (1 minute) but only when a specific event is triggered and only during a certain amount of time.

I've chosen a BackgroundScheduler. My initial idea was to add_job when required then remove_job once the amount of time is over but it seems my job is only executed once.

I tried to use pause / resume but I'm not sure about the behaviour: when I resume, I need to restart a whole interval (1 minute).

What's the correct way to do this?

```
def main():
    global scheduler
...
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(func_monitoring, 'interval', minutes=1, id='monitoring', replace_existing=True)
    scheduler.start()
    scheduler.pause_job('monitoring')
...
    my_stream = ...stream(handler)   # listen to live changes to data, if change, handler is called 


def func_monitoring():
    ...

    if <specific condition> :
        #scheduler.remove_job('monitoring')
        scheduler.pause_job('monitoring')

    ...
    else:
       <my monitoring code>



def handler(message):
    if <specific message received>: 
       #scheduler.add_job(func_monitoring, 'interval', minutes=1, id='monitoring', replace_existing=True)
       scheduler.resume_job('monitoring')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would probably subclassing `IntervalTrigger` and making it so that the initial delay is not applied. The initial delay is there only due to historical reasons.

Comment: Dear Alex, thanks for your answer. I think the current behaviour with the initial delay is OK. My question was more about good practices. When I want to start / stop the intervalTrigger, what do I need to do ? start/pause_job or add / remove job?

Comment: Or keep the job running at each interval and do nothing when not needed?

Comment: There is no need to overwrite `IntervalTrigger`. To skip the initial interval do `scheduler.add_job(..., next_run_time=datetime.datetime.now())`

Comment: Yes, that works too and it's an often used workaround.